# How to use a react component with unordered list inside another jsx page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arraylist, gatsby

I have a custom component with a map like this

```js
const NewComponent = ({ headline, logos}) => {
  return (
<div>
  <h2>{headline}</h2>
  <ul>
    {logos.map(item => {
      return (
        <li>
          <a href={item.link}>
            <img src={item.image} alt="" />
          </a>
        </li>
      );
    })}
  </ul>
</div>
)
})};
```

I am calling this component inside a jsx page like this and this throws an error.

```js
<NewComponent
  headline={a.heading}
  logos={a.image, a.link}
/>
```

I want to know the right way to use the above component in my jsx.

Comment: Please may you reformat the question? (Consider using a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?) What's the error? May you share a [mcve] of the issue you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `logos` the wrong way, it should be an array like :

```
<NewComponent
  headline={a.heading}
  logos={[{image: a.image, link: a.link]}
/>
```

Because you're passing an `Object` it errors because you can't use `.map` on it

Comment: It's not even passing the object they think. `a.image, a.link` will pass `a.link`.